# Suddenly my local SQLServer is kicking named pipe errors

Tags: sql-server

I have a local instance of 64-bit SQL Server Express 12.0.something. I use it for local tests of our SQL code.

Today, out of the blue, I get:

```
Additional information: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 2 - Connection was terminated)
```

I have rebooted and start/stopped the server to no avail. I'm using a database that worked fine the last time I tried it, but to be safe I pulled a backup to no avail.

And it's not a complete failure to work, **it's intermittent. My code does hundreds of queries, and it fails on one of them at random** - a certain query will work the first 10 times and then fail on the 11th, and then the next time I run it, it fails on something else that worked perfectly last time.

Any way to debug this?

Comment: Is the named pipes protocol enabled in the Sql Server Configuration Manager for the instance?

Comment: Yes. I draw your attention to the part where most of the queries work fine and then one fails at random in the middle of the run.

Comment: Would it be possible to provide additional logs from Profiler showing both a good execution of the query and a failure?

Comment: Also, what's your system resource load look like in the run up to the failures?  Are you maxing anything out - CPU, RAM, disk I/O?

Comment: @RobPearson - no, I'm the only user and I'm barely even using it. Loads max around 10% on all of it.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an "answer" per-se, but the only solution was to remove all of SQL and re-install from scratch.

Using the identical databases, versions, software etc. everything once again worked perfectly and the errors vanished.