# Attaching to an existing DB fails - folder keeps setting itself to read only

Tags: sql-server

Having found no solution to the [network problems I suddenly encountered](https://serverfault.com/questions/983976/suddenly-my-local-sqlserver-is-kicking-named-pipe-errors), I uninstalled MSQE but left the MDF files in place. I then re-installed a fresh 2014 and started it up with a test DB from a BAK file.

Now I want to re-attach the original databases. When I try, I get:

CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(Access is denied.) while attempting to open or create the physical file ...'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5123)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=12.00.2269&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=5123&LinkId=20476

The URL is, of course, broken. After some Googling I found this really is just a permissions error, so I went to the DATA folder (who in their febrile imagination thought putting this in Program Files was a good idea?) and found that the folder was set to Read Only.

So I clicked the Read Only check, Applied, and then got Properties again and it was back to Read Only. I cannot seem to get this to "stick", assuming this is the root problem in the first place.

Does anyone have any ideas here?

**UPDATE:** So I gave up trying to fix the tree. I copied all the mdf's and ldfs out to a new folder, c:\databases. I get the same error when I try to attach to them from the new location. I have full control on everything.

Comment: Your problem is not the Read-only attribute. Take a look at the NTFS permissions on the folder. This article explains the Read-only behavior you're seeing. This behavior is still present in current versions of Windows. - https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/326549/you-cannot-view-or-change-the-read-only-or-the-system-attributes-of-fo

Comment: I reset for Full permissions down the entire MSSQL folder tree. No luck. I followed the directions in the note, and the flag does not change.

Comment: I then decided to wipe the entire folder tree. I started by trying to ZIP up DATA, but that failed with Access is denied as well. I am in an admin account with full control. What is going on?

Comment: What user is the SQL server process running under?  This is the user that needs to have permissions on the files/folders in question to make changes.  You can determine which user SQL is starting under by going into SQL configuration manager and looking at the listed user.